# Handling REST calls xml response using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, spring, rest, jaxb

I have sent a GET REST call to "http://services.enterprisecloud.terremark.com/cloudapi/ecloud/organizations/" and the response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Content-Length: 1373 Content-Type: application/vnd.tmrk.cloud.organization; type=collection x-tmrk-currentuser: /cloudapi/ecloud/admin/users/101 x-tmrk-token: cloud-F2A27F74-C04B-4566-AB53-CCC06DA2F798 Date: Thu, 12 May 2011 19:09:13 GMT 
<Organizations href="/cloudapi/ecloud/organizations" type="application/vnd.tmrk.cloud.organization; type=collection" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
.....
.....
```

There is an XSD given by the vendor which didn't generate any class of type Organization or Organizations. The Organization related class generated by JAXB is ArrayOfOrganization which looks like:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ArrayOfOrganizationType", propOrder = {
    "organization"
})
public class ArrayOfOrganizationType {

    @XmlElement(name = "Organization", nillable = true)
    protected List<OrganizationType> organization;
....
....
```

When I try to use the following code:

```
ResponseEntity exchange = template.exchange(URL, 
                    HttpMethod.GET, 
                    new HttpEntity(operation.getInput(), operation.getHeader()), 
                    ArrayOfOrganizationType.class, 
                    urlVariables);
```

The error I get is:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [com.trmk.dto.ArrayOfOrganizationType] and content type [application/vnd.tmrk.cloud.organization;type=collection]
```

In spring-dispatcher.xml, I have following:

```
<!-- Rest client -->
<bean id="httpClient" class="org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="restClient" class="com.transport.ext.RestClient">
</bean>

<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
           <bean id="marshallingHttpMessageConverter" 
            class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter"
            p:marshaller-ref="jaxb2Marshaller" p:unmarshaller-ref="jaxb2Marshaller"
            p:supportedMediaTypes="application/vnd.tmrk.cloud.organization" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jaxb2Marshaller" class="com.util.DefaultJaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>java.lang.String</value>
    <value>com.trmk.dto.ArrayOfOrganizationType</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<!-- End of Rest client -->
```

Any recommendation on how to proceed will be highly helpful as I have run out of ideas to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding `@XmlRootElement(name="Organizations")` to `ArrayOfOrganizationType` although obviously that's not ideal since you'd need to re-add it each time you regenerate the JAXB classes.

Comment: Good suggestion but for the time being I got it resolved by using the xml response I see in Terremark Cloud API explorer and then generating xsd from this xml (of course this xml is partial in the sense that it only deals with one operation). I then used this single operation xsd to generate JAXB classes and the whole thing works with the spring-dispatcher posted above.